# C++ Winsock Download File Cut off HTTP Header

Tags: c++, windows, file, download, winsock

I'm downloading the bytes of a file from the web using winsock2. so good so far.
I have the problem that I download my bytes including the http header which I don't need and which causes troubles in my files bytecodes.

Example:  [image: Example]

I know I can find the position where the header is ending by finding "\r\n\r\n".
But somehow I can't find or at least cut it... :(

```
int iResponseBytes = 0;
ofstream ofDownloadedFile;
ofDownloadedFile.open(pathonclient, ios::binary);
do {
    iResponseBytes = recv(this->Socket, responseBuffer, pageBufferSize, 0);
    if (iResponseBytes > 0)     // if bytes received
    {
        ofDownloadedFile.write(responseBuffer, pageBufferSize);
    }
    else if (iResponseBytes == 0) //Done
    {
        break;
    }
    else //fail
    {
        cout << "Error while downloading" << endl;
        break;
    }
} while (iResponseBytes > 0);
```

I tried searching the array / the pointer using strncmp etc.
Hopefully someone can help me.

Best greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no guarantees, whatsoever, that the `\r\n\r\n` sequence will be received completely within a single `recv()` call.

For example, the first `recv()` call could end up reading everything up until the first two characters of the sequence, `\r\n`, then your code runs around the loop again, and the second time `recv()` gets called it receives the remaining `\r\n` for the initial two bytes received (followed by the first part of the actual content). A small possibility that this might happen, but it cannot be ignored, and must be correctly handled.

If your goal is to trim everything up until the `\r\n\r\n`, your current approach is not going to work very well.

Instead, what you should do is invest some time studying how file stream buffering actually works. Pontificate, for a moment, how `std::istream`/`std::ostream` read/write large chunks of data at a time, but they provide a character-oriented interface. `std::istream`, for example, reads a buffer's full of file data at a time, placing it into an internal buffer, which your code can then retrieve one character at a time (if it wishes to). How does that work? Think about it.

To do this correctly, you need to implement the same algorithm yourself: `recv()` from the socket a buffer at a time, then provide a byte-oriented interface, to return the received contents one byte at a time.

Then, the main code becomes a simple loop, reading the streamed socket contents one byte at a time, at which point discarding everything up until the code sees `\r\n\r\n` becomes trivial (although there are still a few non-obvious gotchas in doing this right, but that can be a new question).

Of course, once the `\r\n\r\n` gets processed, it is certainly possible to optimize things going forward, by flushing out whatever's still buffered internally, to the output file, and then resume reading from the socket a whole buffer-at-a-time, and copying it to the output file without burning CPU cycles dealing with the byte-oriented interface.